# simple dialog (questio, OK, Cancel) with Python using PyQt4

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqt4

I'm trying to transfer a program with GUI from Python+Tkinter to Python+PyQt4. I would like to know if there is a PyQt4-equivalent to the following Tkinter command:

```
tkMessageBox.askokcancel('Question', 'Do you really want to delete all Data?',default='cancel')
```

It should look like this:

[askokcancle using Tkinter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WRqQ.png)

I know, it's possible to create a customized dialog using Qt-Designer, but a simple command using only one line would be nice. I didn't find any solution using common search engines.

Please excuse my english-skills and thanks for reading so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `QMessageBox` and you can do message box in one line of code.

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmessagebox.html

example from page: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/firstprograms/

```
    reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
        "Are you sure to quit?", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | 
        QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

    if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```